# Convertir SQL a Linq Entity Framework con dos Tablas

Tags: sql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-sql

Saludos en este momento tengo esta consulta que me gustaria convertir a Linq con Lambda, estoy trabajando con EF Core.

```
select periodoID, Nombre
from Periodo
where PeriodoID In (select periodoID from grupo where profesorID =215) -- cambiar por la variable idUsuario
order by periodoID desc;
```

gracias por la atención espero me puedan apoyar.

Comment: Seria bueno q ue pusieras una imagen de la estructura de tus tablas